# A question about Rudin's proof that every positive real number has a unique positive $n$-th root

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

I am studying more deeply the first chapters of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*. What interests me are theorems' proofs strategies.
Theorem 1.21 states:

> *For every real $x > 0$ and every integer $n > 0$ there is one and only one real y such that $y^n=x$.*

The *one and only one* part is soon proved; in order to prove the actual existance of $y$, the set

> *$E$ consisting of all positive real numbers $t$ such that $t^n<x$*

is defined and it's then proved that $y=sup(E)$ exists in $R$. It remains to prove that $y^n=x$ and it's done in the last (and quite lenghty) part of the proof.

What I don't understand is why this last part is needed. I would say: once we defined $E$ as above we can consider the set $S$ containing all the upper bounds $f$ of $E$ such that  $f^n \geq x$ right? Among those upper bounds we can consider the smallest one which is indeed $y=sup(E)$ (we know it exists) and being the smallest it is the one such that $y^n = x$.

Am I being incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are being incorrect. If $f$ is an upper bound of $E$, then, yes, $f^n\geqslant x$. But it is not obvious at all that if $f$ is the least upper bound, then $f^n=x$. That equality requires a proof.

Comment: My engineer-background soul screams in pain but I understand the need of that proof now!

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.